# Toggle DIV in Wordpress Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a custom Wordpress template. This is probably a really stupid question, but on a page (not a post) I want to have 4 images, that when they are clicked, corresponding hidden divs slide open, then slide close when the image is clicked again.

I have this in a separate scripts.js file (called for correctly in the template footer.php file - its there so the page loads faster...):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#wd-click').click(function(){
    $('#wd-info').slideToggle();
});

$('#seo-click').click(function(){
    $('#seo-info').slideToggle();
});

$('#mobo-click').click(function(){
    $('#mobo-info').slideToggle();
});

$('#gd-click').click(function(){
    $('#gd-info').slideToggle();
});
```

});

And I have this on the page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="wd-show"><img class="size-full wp-image-93" alt="" src="image.jpg" width="750" height="75" /></a>

<div class="info-div" id="wd-info" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ What's not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: did you put the Jquerry library?

Comment: Do you need to either change your anchor id to wd-click or your jquery target to #wd-show?

Comment: There is no click event bound to "wd-show". Change the first click event or add a new one: $( '#wd-show' ).click( function() { $( '#wd-info' ).slideToggle(); } );

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned all that earlier.

- The div's wd-info, seo-info, mobo-info and gd-info arenet actually toggling at all
- Yes a jQuery library is called
- the jsFiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/MGsPc/ - dont worry about CSS, that was done quickly
- The jQuery targets need to toggle (wd-info etc)

Hope that makes things a bit clearer...

Comment: You had no jquery library selected when I went into it and it was selecting the wrong id. Refer to my answer for a universal solution. For the fiddle you had http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/MGsPc/2/

Comment: Yeah, it works there, but not on my live site...

Comment: This is essentially, what I want, but in WP it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/MGsPc/12/

Answer (score 2):

Try this (because wordpress often runs jQuery in [**no conflict mode**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and doesn't use the $ of jQuery)

```
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    (function($){
    $('#wd-click').click(function(){
        $('#wd-info').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#seo-click').click(function(){
        $('#seo-info').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#mobo-click').click(function(){
        $('#mobo-info').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#gd-click').click(function(){
        $('#gd-info').slideToggle();
    });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DWnff/)

Comment: @MarkTabner, in your fiddle you don't have the ids you have on the jQuery

Comment: Im only showing the one, if that starts to work I'm gonna assume the others will...

Answer (score 0):

you can try lightbox  http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
or twitter bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
for this, really easy and fast to deploy

Comment: I'm trying to steer away from Lightbox or PrettyPhoto, as I dont want an overlay effect for the page. Thanks for that tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You add click event on #wd-click but your link is identified by #wd-show

Comment: Just noticed that, still doesnt make the div toggle. Thanks for pointing it out tho :)

Answer (score 0):

> its there so the page loads faster...):

You can shorten the code and it will reduce the size page though it will have very small impact.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wd-click').click(function(){
      $('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-info' ).slideToggle();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I have a very universal solution for you that is lean and mean on the scripting :p

You can add an id to each one without changing the jQuery if they are different sizes and such.

This can be used with any element as long as you change the class it is selecting.

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageSlide">
  <span class="hidden">I'm a hidden image! :D</span>
</div>
<div class="imageSlide">
  <span class="hidden">I'm a hidden image! :D</span>
</div>
<div class="imageSlide">
  <span class="hidden">I'm a hidden image! :D</span>
</div>
<div class="imageSlide">
  <span class="hidden">I'm a hidden image! :D</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.imageSlide').on('click', function() {
   $(this).children().stop(true).slideToggle('1000'); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.imageSlide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.imageSlide > span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle to above code](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/fhadM/7/)

**JSfiddle with exact needs(I hope)**

**CSS**

```
#img1 {
  background: url(http://remowebdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/web-design.png);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#img2 {
  background: url(http://remowebdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/seo.png);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#img3 {
  background: url(http://remowebdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/mobo.png);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#img4 {
  background: url(http://remowebdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/graphic-design.png);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.info-div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 980px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
  background: #DFE9E7;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle for OP's needs](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/fhadM/6/) (Newest link)

[Another variation I used on one of my portfolios.](http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/CleanPortfolio/index.html)

Comment: Thanks but the divs need to be below an image that is clicked, not inside a div. Close, but no cigar ;)

Comment: Just uploaded a second fiddle link that will have it outside of the main div.

Comment: It's working just fine for me, do you have a library selected under Frameworks & Extensions? It should be automatically set up to that fashion but what is not working?

Comment: Just in case you have a small monitor.. try this fiddle out. http://jsfiddle.net/fhadM/3/

Comment: It's not the monitor, it a 24" iMac I'm using :). I'm using the standard jQuery that is called for in the WP header. The scripts.js is just extra scripts in using in my template, but they all use the standard jQuery. I dont understand whats wrong - I've copied your fiddle exactly, but still not working on my site.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site so I can see what is going on and what version of jQuery are you linking it to?

Comment: Look at my newest fiddle I added to my answer.